# Setting value for specified object

Tags: java, constructor

I assume those are bacics.

I've created 3 objects like this:

```
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        int parkingSlot= 1 + rd.nextInt(3);
        AircraftCarrier ac= new AircraftCarrier (fc, j, parkingSlots, parkingSlots);

    }
```

Based on class AircraftCarrier (it's constructor):

```
public AircraftCarrier (FlightControl fc, int idC, int parkingSlots, int freeParkingSlots) {
    this.kontrolaLotow = fc;
    this.id = idC;
    this.ps = parkingSlots;
    this.fps = freeParkingSlots;        
}
```

So i have 3 Aircraft Carriers, right? Let's assume I need to change freeParkingSLots value for a carrier with id =2. How do I do that?

Comment: Where are your aircraft carrier object kept? In a list? In a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created three instances but since you didn't maintain the reference to any of them, you no longer have them. They have been sent to garbage collection.

You need to store each instance in some collection for later access.

```
 List<AircraftCarrier> myList = new ArrayList<AircraftCarrier>();
 for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    int parkingSlot= 1 + rd.nextInt(3);
    AircraftCarrier ac= new AircraftCarrier (fc, j, parkingSlots, parkingSlots);
    myList.add(ac);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the Carriers in an array:

```
AircraftCarrier[] carriers = new AircreaftCarrier[3];
for (int j = 0; j < carriers.length; j++) {
    int parkingSlot= 1 + rd.nextInt(3);
    AircraftCarrier ac = new AircraftCarrier (fc, j + 1, parkingSlots, parkingSlots);
    carriers[i] = ac;
}
```

Now you are able to access them:

```
carriers[1].fps = 6; // You wanted id=2. Since we count from zero in Java, use 1
```

Comment: I guess, coding after few beers won't work. I'm such a rookie. Ofc both answers are right. I have to accept one. I'm gonna chose list, which is more comfortable to me. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You created each of the instances, but saved them nowhere. So after the loop, the objects are "gone".
Use

```
List<AircraftCarrier> carriers = new ArrayList<AircraftCarrier>();
for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
  int parkingSlot = 1 + rd.nextInt(3);
  AircraftCarrier ac = new AircraftCarrier (fc, j, parkingSlots, parkingSlots);
  carriers.add(ac);
}
```

Since you assigned id 2 to the second element, you can now access it using `carriers.get(1)` (`get(0)` would give you the first element).

Answer (score 1):

You must 'place' the carriers somewhere so that you can access them later:

```
Map<Integer, AircraftCarrier> carriers = new HashMap<Integer, AircraftCarrier>();

for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    int parkingSlot= 1 + rd.nextInt(3);
    AircraftCarrier ac= new AircraftCarrier (fc, j, parkingSlots, parkingSlots);
    carriers.put(j, ac);
}

/* update carrier with ID 2 */
carriers.get(2).fps = 1;
```

Comment: This would only work if the ``AircraftCarrier`` class would override the ``int hashCode()`` method with ``return id;``, never forget that detail when dealing with hashmaps. Also, by contract, you then have to override ``boolean equals(Object o)`` as well!

Comment: @f1sh: No, in this case the key is an Integer which already overrides both , it's not a set :-)

Comment: You are so incredibly right. For some strange reason I thought the AircraftCarrier class was used as the key in the map - please ignore my first incorrect comment, everyone.